# Playing a multi-track file/stream using libvlc (ubuntu)

Tags: c, vlc, libvlc

I'm using the latest vlc version and it doesn't matter if they're in the same window or in multiple windows as long as you can see them all at the same time.

Here's what I was trying:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    libvlc_instance_t *inst;
    libvlc_media_player_t *mp;
    libvlc_media_t *m;

    inst = libvlc_new(0, NULL);
    m = libvlc_media_new_path(inst, "/tmp/mpt-smart-travels-classical-clip.ts");
    mp = libvlc_media_player_new_from_media(m);
    libvlc_media_release(m);
    libvlc_media_player_play(mp);


    libvlc_track_description_t *videoIDs = libvlc_video_get_track_description(mp); 
    int numberOfTracks = sizeof videoIDs;
    int count = 0;
    int id;
    while (count <= numberOfTracks) {
      id = videoIDs[count];
      libvlc_video_set_track(mp,id);
      count += 1;
      }

    sleep(10);

    libvlc_media_player_stop(mp);
    libvlc_media_player_release(mp);
    libvlc_release(inst);


    return 0;
}
```

> $ gcc $(pkg-config --cflags libvlc) -c test.c -o test.o
>
> $ gcc test.o -o test $(pkg-config --libs libvlc)

A pointer called 'p_next' might need to be used to get the IDs of the next stream.
videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxyge/html/structlibvlc_*track*_description__t.html

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific about what you're trying to do ?

The code in the question does not compile, cannot enumerate tracks in any stream.
Below are the minimal changes for that code to become meaningful.

```
#include <vlc/vlc.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    libvlc_instance_t *inst;
    libvlc_media_player_t *mp;
    libvlc_media_t *m;

    if ( argc < 2 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Please provide a file name to open.\n" );
        exit( 1 );
    }

    inst = libvlc_new( 0, NULL );
    m = libvlc_media_new_path( inst, argv[1] );
    mp = libvlc_media_player_new_from_media( m );
    libvlc_media_release( m );
    libvlc_media_player_play( mp );

    sleep( 1 );

    libvlc_track_description_t *track_desc = libvlc_video_get_track_description( mp );
    int numberOfTracks = libvlc_video_get_track_count( mp );

    fprintf( stderr, "numberOfTracks=%d\n", numberOfTracks );

    while ( track_desc != NULL )
    {
        int id = track_desc->i_id;

        if ( id == -1 )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "Not switching to pseudo-track id=%d name=%s\n", id, track_desc->psz_name );
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "Switching to video track id=%d name=%s\n", id, track_desc->psz_name );
            libvlc_video_set_track( mp, id );
        }

        sleep( 1 );
        track_desc = track_desc->p_next;
    }

    fprintf( stderr, "Finished enumerating tracks. Waiting a little.\n" );

    sleep( 10 );

    libvlc_media_player_stop( mp );
    libvlc_media_player_release( mp );
    libvlc_release( inst );


    return 0;
}
```

Again, can you be more specific about what you're trying to do ?